# Acessing base class property when overriding

Tags: python, class, properties, attributes, overriding

Considering the following basic Python classes:

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, a1):
        self._att1 = a1

    @property
    def att1(self):
        return self._att1

    @att1.setter
    def att1(self, a):
        try:
            self._att1 = a
        except TypeError:
            # handle exception
            print("Not allowed")

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self, 100)

    @Foo.att1.setter
    def att1(self, a):
        # self.att1 = a * 0.5  # RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
        # Foo.att1 = a * 0.5  # attribute is not changed (base instances are though (?))
        # Foo.att1(self,a)  # TypeError: 'property' object is not callable
        super().att1.__set__(a * 0.5)   # AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__set__'
        # ... some other additional code ...

a = Foo(5)
b = Bar()
b.att1 = 700

print(a.att1)
print(b.att1)
```

What would be syntax for calling base property setter from within its override on the child class? I understand I could set `self._att1` directly, but I would like to avoid that because I would then need to repeat exception handling code. This but a simple example, and I have more complex cases where the base class implements some additional operations on the attribute, and I would like to avoid repeating the same code on the derived class property setter.

Comment: I think, that `self._att1 = ` is not a bad idea.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I get `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__set__'`

Comment: Sorry, should have been `Foo.att1.__set__(a)`.

Comment: `Foo.att1.__set__(self, a * 0.5)`

Comment: joaocandre: Executing what code was producing the `AttributeError`?

Comment: @martineau accessing it via super, on the instance, not the class.

Comment: @rdas Yes that worked. @jonrsharpe `__set__` complains it needs the `self` argument as well. @martineau I edited the post to include that attempt as well

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I meant the OP is executing some code _outside_ the two class definitions, and I wanted to know what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code:**

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a1):
        self._att1 = a1

    @property
    def att1(self):
        return self._att1

    @att1.setter
    def att1(self, a):
        if not isinstance(a, int):
            print("Not allowed")
        else:
            self._att1 = a


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self, 100)

    @Foo.att1.setter
    def att1(self, a):
        Foo.att1.fset(self, a * 2)


c = Bar()
print(c.att1)
c.att1 = 10
print(c.att1)
c.att1 = "some string"
```

**Output:**

```
100
20
Not allowed
```

---

**UPD.**

Following @chepner advice, I've decided to add some explanation.

When you're using decorator `@Foo.att1.setter` it doesn't work like you expected.

In [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) you can see 2 examples of declaring properties: assign class variable using `property()` function and use `@property` decorator. Both this methods are equialent, but I find first much more obvious in case of demonstration how does provided code works.

Let's rewrite class declarations using `property()` function instead decorators:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a1):
        self._att1 = a1

    def getatt1(self):
        return self._att1

    def setatt1(self, a):
        if not isinstance(a, int):
            print("Not allowed")
        else:
            self._att1 = a

    att1 = property(getatt1, setatt1)

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(100)

    def setatt1(self, a):
        Foo.att1.fset(self, a * 2)

    att1 = property(Foo.getatt1, setatt1)
```

As you see, you don't override property, you're creating new with same name, which shadow base class property. You can prove it using this code:

```
print(f"Foo.att1 is Bar.att1: {Foo.att1 is Bar.att1}")
```

In both declarations it'll return `False`, which means that property objects of this classes aren't same.

Comment: I think the key thing to note is that you are not overriding a method in `Bar`; you are *creating* a brand new property `Bar.att1` by passing `Foo.att1.setter` a new setter method. Within that method, you have to access an attribute of the original *property*, not of `Foo`.

Comment: @chepner: _Why_ exactly do you think it's a key thing to note?

Comment: Because the only way inheritance is involved here is that `Foo` has an attribute named `att1`; you aren't overriding any method of `Foo`. `att1.setter` doesn't return a function; it returns a new instance of `property`. That instance has various function attributes, one of which is `fset`, which gets called from `att1.__set__`. It's the value of `fset` in the new property that is different from the value of `fset` in the original property.

Comment: @chepner: Well, maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet, but that sounds like what one would want... Anyway, I think that using `Foo.att1.__set__()` instead of `Foo.att1.fset()` would be a better way to code it since the former is documented.

Comment: @chepner, added some explanation ;)

Comment: @martineau, `fset` also [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). Quote from docs: `The returned property object also has the attributes fget, fset, and fdel corresponding to the constructor arguments.`

Comment: @OlvinRoght: The linked docs show that `fset` is an argument name. Whereas `__set__()` is a [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) descriptor method.

Comment: @martineau, `fset` is an argument name of `property()` function *(constructor)* **and** an attribute of `property` object.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Oops...that's right—missed that line near the very end of the documentation of `property` class where it mentions this. Also now see it's shown in the "pure Python equivalent" in [Descriptor HowTo guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties). I guess `__set__()` is just better documented in the sense that you can look it up directly instead of searching for it.